# Cron jobs, Scheduling and threading of queries in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cron

I have a large CSV file to upload through codeigniter. It involves a lot of inserts and updates like for 5000 rows it involves 75000 queries to be executed.

Is there a way to process this in the background also is it possible to submit as a `cron` job so that the queries can be executed at a later time? And also, if possible, to limit the number of queries per hour as my host has a limit of max 75000 queries per user per hour? The whole process fails once it crosses that limit.

Comment: Everything is possible with enough time and money; you need to carefully plan your system.

Comment: i think the best way is too separate out all the tables and make different csv for each will this work ??? or use temp table

Comment: I am using temp tables already. Loading of all the files go to temp table and then process it

Answer (score 0):

Seen it take a lot of time to do these jobs.
I deal something like it with "crontab" command under Linux. 
What you get a timeout of execution. have you think about seperation with a more small time of period ? I think giving a hard CPU load is not a good idea for server.

Comment: I like crontab but my client wants to see the execution infront of himself. Is there a way to submit millions of queries at one time and let mysql handle them the way I wanted?

Comment: What about use Json(Post) in client's side operation for multiple submit in order to prevent one request of timeout? In this case,  Each request you could show the response as your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to Cron jobs, Scheduling and threading of queries in Codeigniter

You can set cron in your server.

You can also set flag for executed query.

Example: like **http://domain.com/cron**